# How can I search for duplicate numbers next to each other?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, numeric, capture-group

I'm trying to use `preg_match()` in PHP to make a pattern match for 4 digit numbers that have this pattern:

```
0033
1155
2277
```

Basically the first 2 digits are the same and the last 2 digits are the same, but not all 4 digits are the same.

Is `preg_match()` even the correct function to use? Or should I just split them up and match that way?

Comment: For the record, attempting to use regular expressions for this is quite difficult. It can probably be done but I can't imagine what the result would look like. Needing the two groups to differ in their repeating digits makes it a really difficult regex to write. You're a lot better off using some other solution. If you could dispense with that requirement, `(\d)\1(\d)\2` would probably work.

Comment: @Joel Can I ask what \1 and \2 mean? Because if I had a number 113022 it matches to (\d)\1[30]+(\d)\2. Why? I thought \1 and \2 were position of the number...

Comment: Those are capture group references. That allows you to specify that a capture group should be doubled or tripled or whatever you'd like. You can prevent it from accepting input of that sort by adding boundaries `^(\d)\1(\d)\2$`. That will limit your inputs to 4-digit "words."

Comment: @Joel This actually works for something else I wanted to do. I wanted to match phone numbers using a pattern like so XXYY2XX. The x's and y's could be any number matched with the other x. So 4455233 would be a match for that pattern above. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 3):

To search this kind of number in a text you can use:

```
preg_match('~\b(\d)\1(?!\1)(\d)\2\b~', $str, $m)
```

*(or with `preg_match_all` if you want all of them)*

details:

```
~        # pattern delimiter
\b       # word boundary (to be sure that 1122 isn't a part of 901122)
(\d)     # capture the first digit in group 1
\1       # back-reference to the group 1
(?!\1)   # negative lookahead: check if the reference doesn't follow
(\d)     #
\2       #
\b       # word boundary (to be sure that 1122 isn't a part of 112234)
~        #
```

If you want to check if an entire string is the number, use the string limit anchors in place of word boundaries:

```
~\A(\d)\1(?!\1)(\d)\2\z~
```

Comment: Ok this looks like it. Dunno if I need to create a new question, but taking your code there, is there a way to automatically use this to match any pattern like so? XXYY0 So XX means the same number, YY means the same number but not the same as XX and then 0, just searching for 0. Or the pattern could be XXX0, so 5550 would match. Can you think of a way to write code that dynamically builds your matching code to match whatever pattern being passed?

Comment: Either way I will be accepting your answer, just want to see if we can take it one more step to use to match the pattern I mentioned above.

Comment: @John You can use this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f1589e5e89b0c810662851a978f2696f3632610e

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with a comparison callback:

```
function compare($number) {
    // Compare first 2 numbers
    if (intval($number[0]) !== intval($number[1])) {
        return false;
    }

    // Compare last 2 numbers
    if (intval($number[2]) !== intval($number[3])) {
        return false;
    }

    // Make sure first and last numbers aren't the same
    if (intval($number[0]) === intval($number[3])) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

$data = array_filter($data, 'compare');
```

You could also do this using a closure:

```
$data = array_filter($data, function($number) {
    return intval($number[0]) === intval($number[1]) && intval($number[2]) === intval($number[3]) && intval($number[0]) !== intval($number[3]);
});
```

Examples here: http://ideone.com/0VwJz8

Comment: This answer does not require each character to be a digit, and `str_split()` is not necessary because the same comparisons can be made using string offsets.  Using three separate if statements means code bloat, better to use a single set of conditions like in the anonymous `array_filter()` method.  Casimir's pattern/method performs as desired and can be used in combination with other regex patterns to extract more data in a single step.

Comment: @mickmackusa you're right about not requiring `str_split` however even though it is more code it's more efficient for a single run than using `preg_match` which will be exacerbated over a larger data set: http://ideone.com/SZ7sRW / http://ideone.com/g7Txf8. I broke it down in the method so OP could see what each statement was doing. You can get around the string limitation by casting to an int or using sprintf prior to processing as that will cause strings to fail the third condition since each letter will cast to zero.

Comment: Now it looks like 3 comparisons  and 6 function calls on each iteration.  I'd prefer a single `preg_match()` call.

Comment: We’ll agree to disagree, even with 6 times as many calls it’s roughly 5x more efficient.

Comment: You will see from the OP's comment on Casimir's answer that there are more conditions to include in the task, so the number of non-regex function calls and conditions will increase for the project.  Using a regex solution will provide a one-line single function call per iteration and allow the OP to capture the last character -- all in one step.

Comment: Doing this without a regex isn't a bad idea. You can improve the `compare` function removing `intval` in the last test, but you can also rewrite it for a small performance gain like this: `function compare($j) { return $j[0]==$j[1] && $j[2]==$j[3] && $j[1]!=$j[2] && is_numeric($j); }`. About the performances between this kind of approach and a regex *(and benchmarking in general)*, always keep in mind that you have of course to take account of the first run, but also of the next runs (when the pattern is already compiled).